# Reference a cell by content (Date)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Sheet 1 that has a list of dividend payments that occurred on a certain date (A date, B for payment in USD).

I have another sheet (Sheet 2) that has a list of dates with the exchange rate for that date (A date, B USD->GBP)

I want to add a third column to the Sheet 1 to take the date, look up the exchange rate on that date and populate it in column C.

Googling shows a lot of formatting of dates but not my exact requirement.

How do you reference a cell by content (in this case date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. Adapt the following formula to reflect your sheetnames (Sheet2 being my 1st sheet, Sheet3 being my 2nd) and ranges.

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet3!$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I added that and get 'N/A' for my result.  Here is my exact calculation: ```=INDEX('Exchange Rate'!$B$3:$B$390,MATCH(Dividends!$A2,'Exchange Rate'!$A$3:$A$390,0))```

Comment: would it be because one is a date and the other is a date-time pair? EDIT: Seems like it,  I was able to get the correct row for just the match.  I don't want to go through 3,000 lines deleting the time part.

Comment: INT() fixed my date-time issue.

Comment: @graham.reeds I was about to write about the INT function. Glad you found the solution.